# Change the C++ Build command line options with Eclipse

Tags: configuration, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse 3.8 `File>Properties` displays a window: **Properties for hw.cpp**. `C/C++ Build>Settings` shows: **Settings** with the tab: **Tool Settings** containing these text field values:

**Command:**

```
g++
```

**All options:**

```
-O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0
```

I would like to add `-std=c++1y` but the **All options** field is not editable. How do I change the command line options?

The **Command** field is editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File>Properties` displays a window: **Properties for hw.cpp**.

`C/C++ Build>Settings` shows: **Settings** with: **GCC C++ Compiler/Micellaneous** containing this text field:

**Other flags**

```
-c -fmessage-length=0
```

Change to:

```
-c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++1y
```

The change will show in the uneditable field, **All Options**.

Answer (score 0):

good answers. Just to add: Under the GCC C++ or GCC C compiler subtabs (dialect, preprocessor, etc) you will find the various settings that are collected in the "all options" box. That box just shows the sum total of what you selected elsewhere.